# Fading Banner Using `background:url()`

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a banner enclosed in a `div` tag that contains my banner. I would like to get the banner to fade to the next image but unsure how to achieve the fading effect. I have tried using jQuery fadeIn() but it failed.

The reason why I need to use the `background: url()` is because I want this banner image to resize pleasantly when the browser gets resized. I am not sure if this is the best way of approaching my problem.

EDIT - My current code does swap the images in the banner, but does not apply the fadeIn() effect. The console does not report any errors.

CSS:

```
header div#banner {
    background: url(../image/banner/00.jpg) no-repeat center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 300px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var bannerImages = new Array();
var bannerCounter = 0;

function run() {
    loadBannerImages();
    runBannerTimer();
}

function loadBannerImages() {
    var filePath = "image/banner/";
    bannerImages[0] = filePath + "00.jpg";
    bannerImages[1] = filePath + "01.jpg";
    bannerImages[2] = filePath + "02.jpg";
    bannerImages[3] = filePath + "03.jpg";
    bannerImages[4] = filePath + "04.jpg";
}

function runBannerTimer() {
    var t=setTimeout("swapBannerImage()",2000);
}

function swapBannerImage() {
    $('#banner').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $('#banner').css('background', 'url(' + bannerImages[bannerCounter] + ') no-repeat center');
    });
    bannerCounter++;

    if (bannerCounter >= bannerImages.length) {
        bannerCounter = 0;
    }

    runBannerTimer();
}
```

Comment: Did you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @dSquared The console did not report any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setTimeout isn't correct; try the following instead:

```
function runBannerTimer() {
    var t=setTimeout(function(){
        swapBannerImage()
    },2000);
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the updated Banner Swap function:

```
function swapBannerImage() {
    $('#banner').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#banner').css('background', 'url(' + bannerImages[bannerCounter] + ') no-repeat center').fadeIn('slow');
    });

    bannerCounter++;

    if (bannerCounter >= bannerImages.length) {
        bannerCounter = 0;
    }

    runBannerTimer();
}
```

[Updated Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6YpjY/1/)

Comment: I saw your demo and it does swap the images. When I applied your code to my local, I did not see the fadeIn() effect.

Comment: @user1277607 Here is the updated fiddle; I added the fadeOut and fadeIn effect. http://jsfiddle.net/6YpjY/1/

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to not get the image to fadeOut() as that is creating that white flash I am trying to avoid. I tried replacing the `fadeOut()` with a `fadeIn()` but that did not do the trick.

Comment: @user1277607 This requires some cloning and additional css; here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6YpjY/2/

Comment: I tried your code and it is getting to almost where I need it to be :) I noticed that you insert $clone after $that, which causes the contents of my page to be pushed down for a split second. I'm trying to adjust your code to fix that glitch. I also noticed that the first time you run the code, the image zooms into the first image before rotating to the next one.

Comment: @user1277607 its not a gltich; you need to add the css rules form the fiddle as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple divs -- one per image -- and fade them in/out. The divs could still use the css `background` like you want, you'll just need to absolutely position them, so that they appear one on top of another. However, to get absolutely positioned divs to resize with the parent div (ie to get the "pleasant" resizing effect), you have to set up the css like so:

```
header div#banner {
    ... /* your background stuff here */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Note that you'll assign both `left` and `right`, which would make it take up the entire width of the parent. And, make sure that the parent has `position:relative`.